# How to solve: $\int _0 ^1 x (1+x)^n dx$?

Tags: calculus

> Solve: $\int _0 ^1 x (1+x)^n dx$?

---

Original question: find $ \sum _{r=1}^n [(^nC _r)/(r+2)] $

---

In order to solve this question, I planned to integrate $x(1+x)^n$, this gives a wrong answer : $$\frac {2n(2^n) ( 3n+4)}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Ps: I'm bad at calculus.

Comment: Hint: Beta function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sub $x=u-1$, then the integral is

$$\int_1^2 du (u-1) u^n$$

Comment: Why can't I use integration by parts ( I.e. $\int uv dx= u\int vdx -\int u' (\int v dx) dx$? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Harshal: Why do you want to? Ron's integral is about as simple as they get.

Comment: Actually I found my mistake. Anyways, thanks for your help guys. Substituting x = u-1 is far better. :)

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $x(1+x)^n = (1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Though tagged as "Calculus", I want add an algebraic solution

$$(n+2)(n+1)\binom nr\frac1{(r+2)}=(r+1)\binom{n+2}{r+2}=[(r+2)-1]\binom{n+2}{r+2}$$

$$=(n+2)\binom{n+1}{r+1}-\binom{n+2}{r+2}$$

$$\implies(n+2)(n+1)\sum_{r=1}^n\binom nr\frac1{r+2}=(n+2)\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n+1}{r+1}-\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n+2}{r+2}$$

$$=(n+2)\left[(1+1)^{n+1}-\binom{n+1}0-\binom{n+1}1\right]-\left[(1+1)^{n+2}-\binom{n+2}0-\binom{n+2}1-\binom{n+2}2\right]$$

Now simplify